# Can any discretization scheme reproduce the kane quasi-linear dispersion relation?

Tags: finite-difference, eigensystem

It is straightforward to solve the eigenproblem $$\hat{k}^2 \psi = E\psi$$using a finite-difference method. But what about$$\hat{k}^2 \psi = E(1+\alpha E)\psi$$I know it is possible to first solve the case where $\alpha = 0$ and then work out $E$ by solving the quadratic equation $\alpha E^2 + E - E' = 0$. But is it possible to write down some operator, discretizeable with finite-difference, that reproduces the same dispersion?

Comment: Why would you *not* want to solve $k^2\psi = \lambda \psi$ and then in a second step solve the (scalar) equation $\lambda = E(1-\alpha E)$?